# How can I import a tab delimited (TSV) file saved on Google Drive into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

I saved a TSV file (it has to be TSV because reasons... I guess it could be .xlsx too), on my drive and I want to import it using `=importdata("https://drive.google.com/open?id=<myfileID>")`

This... almost works, but it seems to want to give each character a column (except that my data doesn't even have that characters.  The error is:

```
Error
Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more columns (1096).
```

My data has 13 columns, and browsing the data in a text editor, has max about 125 characters. So even allocating a character per column it should still be able to show it

I've saved sample TSV and Sheets document, so perhaps you guys can help me out.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ri_FJ-ty9rB408KTzeLUGm8om4JX8q_Mh6x7Eh7bbIQ/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijERb-QPmeYA_GrcjB3dCckNKU2XiSd8/view?usp=sharing (the tsv file)

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*You need to use the export/download link, rather than the share link.*

#### Modification:

```
=IMPORTDATA(https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1ijERb-QPmeYA_GrcjB3dCckNKU2XiSd8&export=download)
```

You can get this link by visiting the share link for your TSV file, and hitting download in the top-right. A new tab will open that contains the URL of the export link.

You can also take the imported data and use the `SPLIT` function to separate the tabular data using `CHAR(9)`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA(A3),CHAR(9),FALSE,TRUE))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `File > Import > [Select File]` menu item, then use the `Append to current Sheet` and `Tab` separator type to import any TSV file on your Drive to a Sheet.

Comment: This brings it in! But it thinks it's a CSV and not a TSV or text.  Any idea how I can change this to know it's a TSV (importdata help says it can import both, but it seems to think it's CSV).  I think I can edit the source to try to not include commas, I'm sure that will help.

Comment: I updated my answer with a second solution, let me know if this is helpful. Does the TSV file dynamically change at all?

Comment: That second way worked like a charm thanks! (is that linked or is that a once off import?)

Comment: ```=arrayformula(split(IMPORTDATA(A3),char(9),false,true))``` works great

Comment: What about the `ARRAYFORMULA` version isn't working?

Comment: It says "Could not fetch https://https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1ijERb-QPmeYA_GrcjB3dCckNKU2XiSd8".  Oh it's me I removed the &export=download from A3... Dunno why I did that

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore. I am trying to find new solutions...

Comment: @PepSakdoek can you explain what the problem is? I don't see why it shouldn't still work

Comment: If you visit the sheet linked in the question, it used to import the tsv file fine (with the formula in cell A11).  Now it imports the HTML   I've expanded the sheet to give each formula enough space to spill, but in the past the values would come through and not the HTML. Or on other methods it gives; ERROR Could not fetch url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijERb-QPmeYA_GrcjB3dCckNKU2XiSd8/view?usp=sharing